# Как работают исключения?

Tags: java, исключения

```
public class DogIsNotReadyException extends Exception {

    public DogIsNotReadyException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}

public class Dog {

    String name;
    boolean isCollarPutOn;
    boolean isLeashPutOn;
    boolean isMuzzlePutOn;

    public Dog(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void putCollar() {

        System.out.println("Ошейник надет!");
        this.isCollarPutOn = true;
    }

    public void putLeash() {

        System.out.println("Поводок надет!");
        this.isLeashPutOn = true;
    }

    public void putMuzzle() {
        System.out.println("Намордник надет!");
        this.isMuzzlePutOn = true;
    }

    public void walk() throws DogIsNotReadyException {

        System.out.println("Собираемся на прогулку!");
        if (isCollarPutOn && isLeashPutOn && isMuzzlePutOn) {
            System.out.println("Ура, идем гулять! " + name + " очень рад!");
        } else {
            throw new DogIsNotReadyException("Собака " + name + " не готова к прогулке! Проверьте экипировку!");
        }
    }
}


public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws DogIsNotReadyException {
        Dog dog = new Dog("Rex");
        dog.putCollar();
        dog.putMuzzle();
        dog.walk();
    }
}
```

Почему вот этот код выводит в консоль:

```
Ошейник надет!
Намордник надет!
Собираемся на прогулку!
Exception in thread "main" DogIsNotReadyException: Собака Rex не готова к прогулке! Проверьте экипировку!
    at Dog.walk(Dog.java:35)<br>
    at Test.main(Test.java:6)
```

А вот ниже пример, выводит вот это:

```
Ошейник надет! 
Намордник надет! 
Собираемся на прогулку! 
Собака Мухтар не готова к прогулке! Проверьте экипировку! 
Проверяем снаряжение! Ошейник надет? true
Поводок надет? false 
Намордник надет? true
```

Вот пример:

```
public class DogIsNotReadyException extends Exception {

    public DogIsNotReadyException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}


public class Dog {

    String name;
    boolean isCollarPutOn;
    boolean isLeashPutOn;
    boolean isMuzzlePutOn;

    public Dog(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void putCollar() {

        System.out.println("Ошейник надет!");
        this.isCollarPutOn = true;
    }

    public void putLeash() {

        System.out.println("Поводок надет!");
        this.isLeashPutOn = true;
    }

    public void putMuzzle() {
        System.out.println("Намордник надет!");
        this.isMuzzlePutOn = true;
    }

    public void walk() throws DogIsNotReadyException {

        System.out.println("Собираемся на прогулку!");
        if (isCollarPutOn && isLeashPutOn && isMuzzlePutOn) {
            System.out.println("Ура, идем гулять! " + name + " очень рад!");
        } else {
            throw new DogIsNotReadyException("Собака " + name + " не готова к прогулке! Проверьте экипировку!");
        }
    }
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args)  {
        Dog dog = new Dog("Rex");
        dog.putCollar();
        dog.putMuzzle();
        try{
            dog.walk();
        } catch (DogIsNotReadyException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            System.out.println("Проверяем снаряжение! \n Ошейник надет? " + dog.isCollarPutOn + "\r\n Поводок надет? "
                    + dog.isLeashPutOn + "\r\n Намордник надет? " + dog.isMuzzlePutOn);
        }
    }
}
```

Вопросы:

1. Почему первый пример не работает если мы метод `main` помечаем `throws`? Должно же одинаково отрабатывать как с первым примером так и со вторым. Ну либо `throws` либо `try catch` должно быть.
2. Не понимаю как отрабатывает метод `getMessage()`, залез в исходники и увидел вот это:

   ```
   public String getMessage() {
       return detailMessage;
   }
   ```

   Посмотрел что такое `detailMessage` это просто переменная, не очень всё равно понял как это отрабатывает.
   Для проверки сделал вот так:

   ```
   public class Test {
       public static void main(String[] args)  {
           Dog dog = new Dog("Rex");

           try{
               dog.walk();
           } catch (DogIsNotReadyException e) {
               System.out.println(e.getMessage());
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   Вывелось в консоль:

   ```
   Собираемся на прогулку!
   Собака Rex не готова к прогулке! Проверьте экипировку!
   ```

   В вызове метода walk отрабатывает

   ```
   System.out.println("Собираемся на прогулку!");
   ```

   А вот потом отрабатывает `throw new DogIsNotReadyException("Собака " + name + " не готова к прогулке! Проверьте экипировку!");` но только когда  `System.out.println(e.getMessage());` мы написали, не понимаю как отрабатывает код.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Примеры работают.

Исключение необходимо ловить, иначе оно выбрасывается выше, на уровень управляющего кода.

Это справедливо и для функции `main`

В первом примере вы его пробрасываете наружу

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws DogIsNotReadyException {
```

тем самым указывая что не хотите заботится об обработке этого исключения и возлагаете эту ответственность на того, кто запускает функцию `main`. результат выброса - завершение программы с выводом этого исключения, чисто технически это механизм отработает так же как и внутри программы.

ОС узнает об исключении и может предпринять действия по его обработке.

Представьте что Ваша программа по выгулу собак часть чего-то большего. Управляющий код так же должен узнать о нештатных ситуациях и уметь например перезапустить Вашу программу.

PS: `getMessage` это метод акцессор для поля `message` у исключения, оно выводит строку, которая была передана в конструктор исключения и там запомнена в переменную `message`

Comment: Не очень понимаю момент с методом getMessage() как отрабатывает

Comment: @ПетровченкоИван я уже написал PS, теперь понятно?

Comment: Сейчас детально разберу и если что напишу)